# json data getting from url is not parsed in handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

I want to parse JSON data that I am getting from url in handlebars.
What I tried is I got the JSON data from the url. 
I defined it into data object.
I want to know how can I parse the data using handlebars.js 
I am new to handlebars.js
Is there any other way in which we can get without defining each property?
Because my JSON data is huge.
for eg.

```
reportData = {
        inquiryId= data.data[0].inquiryId;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<script id="address-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#with data}}
  <p> My id is  {{{inquiryId}}}</p>
  {{/with}}
</script>
<div class="content-placeholder"></div>
```

JS code:

```
var reportData= {};
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url: reportURL,
            success : function (data){
                var inquiryId= data.data[0].inquiryId;

                var theTemplateScript = $("#address-template").html();
                console.log(theTemplateScript);
                // Compile the template
                var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(theTemplateScript);

               // Define our data object
                reportData=data;
                console.log(reportData);
                // Pass our data to the template
                var theCompiledHtml = theTemplate(reportData);

                // Add the compiled html to the page
                $('.content-placeholder').html(theCompiledHtml);
            }

        })
    });
```

JSON:

```
{  
   "success":true,
   "errors":{  

   },
   "authenticated":true,
   "program":1,
   "data":[  
      {  
         "id":1,
         "date":1505756267000,
         "name":"AKKAYA, JORGE",
         "productName":"Credit Profile",
         "inquiryId":726608
      }
   ]
}
```

My output is: 
My id is

Can anyone help me out? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your Json, data contains array and in your html you are treating it like single object. So please use the below handlebar format to iterate over it.

```
{{#with abc}}
  {{#each this}}
    <p> My id is  {{{inquiryId}}}</p>
  {{/each}}
{{/with}}
```